# Why can I use a large buffer as a vector but not with new on Windows?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, 64-bit

I'm using 64 bit Windows 7 Pro and Visual Studio 2010 Pro.

I'm trying to allocate and use a buffer that is bigger than 4 GB (for high data rate data capture).

Allocating and writing the buffer as a vector of bytes works fine. Allocating the buffer as an array of bytes works fine, but writing to that array crashes quickly. (The last message printed is "buffer allocated".)

Commenting out the vector section does not fix the problem.

The following is my test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <BaseTsd.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  const ULONG64 BUF_SIZE = 4 * 1024ULL * 1024ULL * 1024ULL;

  {
    vector<unsigned __int8> v(BUF_SIZE);
    cout << "vector allocated" << endl;
    for (ULONG64 i = 0; i < BUF_SIZE; ++i) {
      v[i] = 0xff;
    }
    cout << "vector written" << endl;
  }

  {
    unsigned __int8* buffer = new unsigned __int8[BUF_SIZE];
    cout << "buffer allocated" << endl;
    for (ULONG64 i = 0; i < BUF_SIZE; ++i) {
      buffer[i] = 0xff;
    }
    cout << "buffer written" << endl;
    delete[] buffer;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: I believe this is a compiler bug. See here:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/553756/invalid-check-for-maximum-array-size-in-x64-compiler-c2148

Comment: I am using the 64 bit compiler, by the way, and dumpbin /headers shows `8664 machine (x64)` and `Application can handle large (>2GB) addresses`.

Comment: Does `buffer` look like a reasonable pointer after the allocation? At what `i` does it crash?

Comment: after you allocate the vector, can you print out `v.size()` to confirm no variables were truncated along the way?

Comment: Search your source files and library headers for bad definitions of `size_t` as a 32-bit integer.

Comment: The address of `v`'s buffer is 0x13F8A0040. The address of `buffer` is 0xC2510. The crash happens immediately on my virtual machine, though it happened at about 40000 bytes in on real hardware.

Comment: `v.size()` is 4294967296, as expected. `sizeof(size_t)` is 8.

Comment: I bet you've found a 64/32 bug in the default implementation of `new`. :-) Vector uses a default allocator which may not even use `new` in its implementation.

Comment: @Omnifarious - Ha! I've labored for many years training myself that it's never the compiler's fault!

Comment: @JimHunziker: I have not thoroughly suppressed that particular thought. I have, in fact, found a few compiler bugs in my time. So, when I suspect one, I still try to narrow down the problem really carefully, and usually discover I'm wrong. But I'm certainly not above suspecting as the false positive rate has been like 95%, not 100%.

Comment: @JimHunziker: that's a 32-bit address. If you want to allocate that much memory, you'll need to compile a 64-bit application.

Comment: In Java, you have to create an array of buffers.

Comment: @jalf: The address of `v` can't be 32 bits. It is 33 bits long. I agree that the address of `buffer` is 32 bits, but both addresses were printed from the same program. Because of this and because of `dumpbin`'s results, I definitely compiled it as a 64 bit application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried compiling the given code with VS2010 Pro (64-bit version), and the compiler produced a [C2148 error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0z0bbfe.aspx) for the `new` call:

```
error C2148: total size of array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes
```

I compiled it from the command line after running `vcvarsx86_amd64.bat`. It seems that the [limit given here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4yyh3a9.aspx) is maybe somehow coming into play.  Changing the `new` to `[BUF_SIZE-1]` allowed it to compile and run (although that is still larger than the 0x7fffffff number discussed in those links).

Comment: I believe you were not doing a 64 bit build. I'm compiling using cl.exe from the 64 bit command prompt, but you can also make an x64 Solution Platform from the IDE.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis:  Indeed.  I was puzzling over that one as well.  It seems maybe as if maybe there is a compiler bug (but every time I think that, it somehow turns out to be something I goofed up or interpreted incorrectly).

Comment: You can confirm that your executable is a 64 bit executable by running dumpbin /headers on it from a Visual Studio command prompt and reading the first few lines.

Comment: @JimHunziker:  It does indicate 64-bit (`8664 machine (x64)`).  Possibly of interest is that I compiled this from the command line (after running vcvarsx86_amd64.bat).

Comment: Weird. The only way I can get your error is if I try to compile from the x86 (regular) command prompt.

Comment: @JimHunziker:  That is odd.  Typing `cl` tells me the version is Version 16.00.30319.01 for x64.  Perhaps a different version?

Comment: Interestingly, that link says that the limitation is due to size_t being 32 bits. But `sizeof(size_t)` (as mentioned by @edA-qa mort-ora-y in the question's comments) is 8.

Comment: My `cl` version is the same. I'm compiling with no flags except for `/EHsc`.